# Does XMPP (CCS) provide canonical Id on a ACK response?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I started working with GCM and just recently changed from HTTP protocol to XMPP protocol in order to handle upstream messages from the phone.

I could not find an example or article that states that a canonical ID will be returned for an ack response.

Has someone confirmed that this will happen for XMPP protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link confirms that, at least up to Feb 17 (2015), this was not the case:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/1MMTAdqYYqE

<strike>I haven't seen anything new about that, so I believe it to still be valid. So, no canonical IDs for XMPP.</strike>

But it has been implemented as `canonical_ids` since Jul 27 (2015):

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream

Answer (score 0):

With the new Firebase you can get a canonical ID as part of the ACK Message:

> **registration_id**   *Optional, string*
>
> This parameter specifies the
>   canonical registration token for the client app that the message was
>   processed and sent to. A canonical registration ID is the registration
>   token of the last registration requested by the client app. This is
>   the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the device.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#downstream